# OpenGL ES compile errors

Tags: eclipse, opengl-es, android-ndk

When trying to write these functions in eclipse with android NDK errors given that there are invalid arguments and such:

```
m_Display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
m_Surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(m_Display, lConfig,
        m_Application->window, NULL);
```

The errors:

1. `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void * eglGetDisplay(?)`
2. `Type 'EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY' could not be resolved`
3. `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void *
   eglCreateWindowSurface(void *, void *, ?, const int *)`

The tooltip eclipse gives when hovering over these functions shows 
questionmarks as input variables. I think eclipse isn't finding some code it should be including but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you include #include <EGL/egl.h> in your code?

Comment: yes i have :) its in cluded in the .hpp file

Comment: im now thinking eclipse doesnt recognize anything foram eglplatform.h which is included and know but apparently ignored.
still have no idea how to fix it though

Comment: issue was to use eglplatform.h you apparently have to add __ANDROID__ as a SYMBOL in your project properties c/c++ buil in elipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this go to your projects properties and go to the "C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols" page, under the **"Symbols"** tab click on GNU C and then the "Add" button and put

```
__ANDROID__
```

in the **NAME** field (value leave blank) and click OK. You can do the same for GNU C++.